# Formatting Header Dictionary for Requests in Python

Tags: python, header, python-requests

I have the following format for request headers:

```
{
  "projectName": New001,
  "cloudRegions":{"REGION1":"centralus"},
  "cloudAccountName":"XXX-XXXX-XXXX"
}
```

How do I format this to accept the {"REGION1":"centralus"}?

My Python code:

```
url = 'www.myexample.com'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'projectName': New001,
       'cloudRegions':{'REGION1':'centralus'},
       'cloudAccountName':'XXX-XXXX-XXXX'
      }

 r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

The problem is I can't make the request to where cloudRegions will be formatted correctly. The value is in dictionary format but it doesn't like that. I've tried wrapping it in str(), using json.loads(), json.dumps(), but it always ends up formatted wrong. How do I format it to be an object that will be accepted as a  pair?

This CURL works, and you will see the same format:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "projectName": "New001", \ 
   "cloudRegions":{"REGION1":"centralus"}, \ 
   "cloudAccountName":"XXX-XXXX-XXXX" \ 
 }' 'http://www.myexample.com'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Well the API rejects it, 400. It wants the <K,V> for regions as specified (string, <k,v> pair)

Comment: So is it just looking for 'REGION1,centralus' - just make it a string.

Comment: Sounds like its on the API's side. If `cloudRegions` is found by the API, then it inspects its value and doesn't see a `dict` or turns a `str` to `dict` somehow, then it will fail.

Comment: pstatix, exactly. It wants the exact value as <K,V> where K = string and V = <k, v>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HTTP headers to send your data (which is *very unusual*), while your curl example clearly shows that you must send the data in HTTP body, formatted as JSON. `requests` can do that very easily.

So simply use:

```
url = 'www.myexample.com'

data = {'projectName': 'New001',
        'cloudRegions': {'REGION1':'centralus'},
        'cloudAccountName': 'XXX-XXXX-XXXX'
       }

 r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Such a newbie mistake! I spent hours researching how to do with headers before I noticed the curl option "-d"